# AngularJS: how to change location path in routeChangeStart event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

In my application I'm using some query string parameters to resolve links for preselecting some data. But I would like to hide these parameters for users. For example, where I'm using a route like `localhost/myapp#/settings?key=dataGrid&value=10`, I want to clear these parameters and show user a route like `localhost/myapp#/settings`.

I tried something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.run(['$rootScope', '$sce', '$location', '$route',
    function($rootScope, $sce, $location, $route) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
            if ($location.url().indexOf('?key=')) {
                var newLocationPath = $location.url().substring(
                    0, $location.url().indexOf('?key='));
                $location.path(newLocationPath).search('');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

But it does not do anything. On StackOverflow I found something about using `$rootScope.$Apply`, but if it try it, I get this error: `[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`.

Comment: why passing parameter through URL ? it's not really a good idea, create a service instead. Betting 2$ that you haev a PHP background ;)

Comment: @Bixi - maybe it'd be helpful to provide an example of what you mean of using a service instead. And explain why you feel it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Try: **$locationChangeStart** to handle page changes. Your code would be as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){
    $rootScope.target = $location.search()['key']; // (equivalent) key = GET[key]
    // $rootScope.target = $location.search().key; // Other solution
});
```

To set a parameter to the url from a controller (without use of a link), the code is as follows:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $location) {

    // setParam('key', 'dataGrid')
    $scope.setParam = function(param, value) {
        $location.search(param, value); // domain.com/#/page?key=dataGrid
    };

});
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Chofoteddy/3wFeR/

That said, your code would be as follows:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){
    var param = $location.search()['key'];
    $location.path(param).search(''); // Change url and clean params
});
```

More info: [$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart")](http://bit.ly/1mDIg7F)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! Here: http://jsfiddle.net/3wFeR/2/ I add two functions. Its interesting but my first function 'clearUrlKeysBad' not work in my project. Maybe becouse different version of AngularJS..? But my second function 'clearUrlKeysRigt' work for me. Whats different between setting $location.path and $location.url?

Comment: That's right, in fact I find a better solution you posted the previous comment. 

"$location.url" acts on the full address in the browser, while "$location.path" on the slash (/).